# add a column between two columns of a gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn

I used a datagridview in my winform application.
I load datagrid with a dataset that have 4 columns.
Next I want to add a column between column2 & column3.
How to I do this.
Thanks.

Comment: GridView or DataGridView. Two very different controls on different platforms. Clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert.aspx) method on DataGridView.Columns collection. For example,

```
var column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
// initialize column properties
...
myGridView.Columns.Insert(2, column);
```

Preferably, this should happen after the data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Visual Studio Designer, you can simply add columns of every kind in the options of the DGV.

You can even set the position of the columns by drag&drop.

If you can't or don't want to use the Designer VinayC told you to do it the code-way.